# How to add two array into one as multidimensional in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am having a Laravel form and there is a column "qty", if we enter more than 1 qty than that number of times the same data will get entered. for that, I want to combine the data in an array to insert at the same time. below are the codes:

```
$code  = time();
        $array = array();
        for ($qty = 0; $qty < $e->qty; $qty++) {
            $array = array_push($array, array(
                'coupon_code'   => $code + $qty,
                'amount'        => $e->amount,
                'expiry_date'   => $e->expiry_date,
                'assigned_to'   => $e->user_id,
                'assigned_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'created_by'    => session('admin_id'),
            ));
        }
DB::table('coupons')->insert($array);
```

But array push is giving error

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, int given

How can I make it a multi dimentional array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)  is defined as...

> array_push ( array &$array [, mixed $... ] ) : int

so the return value is an int ...

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

So when you call it in...

```
$array = array_push($array, array(
```

`$array` will be set to the number of elements in the array, you should change this to...

```
array_push($array, array(
```

Answer (score 1):

just use like this :

```
array_push($array, array(
            'coupon_code'   => $code + $qty,
            'amount'        => $e->amount,
            'expiry_date'   => $e->expiry_date,
            'assigned_to'   => $e->user_id,
            'assigned_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'created_by'    => session('admin_id'),
        ));
```

Comment: that looks a lot like the solution posted by @Nigel Ren - what does your solution bring to the table that Nigel's doesn't, in your view?